# How to decide which extension to use, an even or an odd one? IBVP Problem

Tags: fourier-series

How does one decide whether to compute an odd or an even extension of a function when solving an IBVP. For example:

Solve the following IBVP
$$PDE : u_t(x, t) = 3u_{xx}(x, t) \text{ for } 0<x<2 \text{ and } t > 0$$
$$BC : u(0, t) = 0, u(2, t) = 0, t ≥ 0$$
$$IC : u(x, 0) = x^2 \text{ for } 0 ≤ x ≤ 2$$
The solution suggests computing an odd extension. Why an odd one and not an even extension I cannot understand. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Probably because $u(0,t) = u(2,t) = 0.$ that matches $\sin\left( \dfrac{2\pi n t} 2 \right). \qquad$